# Type Error: Cannot read the property of "user" of null

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am making a server info command in discord.js but got the error

`Cannot read property of "user" of null`

It works before, but now it does not. I have no idea why

Here is the code that has the problem:

```
 .addField("Owner", `${message.guild.owner.user.username}#${message.guild.owner.user.discriminator}`, true)
```

Comment: Just check if your message object contains the attribute 'guild' . If yes then check if 'guild' has the attribute 'owner'.

Comment: The error is telling you that `message.guild.owner` is null.

Comment: Try to fetch members in the guild first, `message.guild.owner` retrieves the `GuildMember` from members cache with owner id.